# JMeter Error While Opening JMX Script: Character reference "&#x0" is an invalid XML character

Tags: jmeter

I wrote a load test script for a company. But two days ago, I saved my changes and left the computer. After that, when I try to open the JMX script, I keep seeing this error on my terminal window: `[Fatal Error] :4202:72: Character reference "&#x0" is an invalid XML character.`

Please help me to solve this issue. I have no idea what to do. I can send you the JMX script if you want.

Tried with: JMeter 5.1.1 and 5.4.1

Full log at jmeter.log file:

```
2022-02-07 12:47:19,759 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: /Users/admin/Desktop/MW ÖN YÜZ/frontend_PegasusLoadium2022.jmx
2022-02-07 12:47:19,837 WARN o.j.r.p.TestPlanAnalyzer: Cannot parse file: /Users/admin/Desktop/MW ÖN YÜZ/frontend_PegasusLoadium2022.jmx
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "&#x0" is an invalid XML character.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.0.jar:?]
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121) ~[?:1.8.0_311]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.plugins.TestPlanAnalyzer.getNodeListWithClassNames(TestPlanAnalyzer.java:106) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.6.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.plugins.TestPlanAnalyzer.analyze(TestPlanAnalyzer.java:36) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.6.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.plugins.PluginSuggester.analyzeTestPlan(PluginSuggester.java:51) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.6.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.plugins.PluginSuggester.findPluginsToInstall(PluginSuggester.java:44) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.6.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.plugins.PluginSuggester.checkAndSuggest(PluginSuggester.java:28) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.6.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.logging.LoggerAppender.append(LoggerAppender.java:33) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.6.jar:?]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156) ~[log4j-core-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129) ~[log4j-core-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120) ~[log4j-core-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84) ~[log4j-core-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:464) ~[log4j-core-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:448) ~[log4j-core-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:431) ~[log4j-core-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:406) ~[log4j-core-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63) ~[log4j-core-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146) ~[log4j-core-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2170) ~[log4j-api-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2125) ~[log4j-api-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2108) ~[log4j-api-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2019) ~[log4j-api-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1890) ~[log4j-api-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.info(Log4jLogger.java:184) ~[log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.loadTree(SaveService.java:428) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:130) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doActionAfterCheck(Load.java:89) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.doAction(AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.java:45) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:70) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311) [?:1.8.0_311]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758) [?:1.8.0_311]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97) [?:1.8.0_311]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709) [?:1.8.0_311]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703) [?:1.8.0_311]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_311]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74) [?:1.8.0_311]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728) [?:1.8.0_311]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205) [?:1.8.0_311]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116) [?:1.8.0_311]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105) [?:1.8.0_311]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:1.8.0_311]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93) [?:1.8.0_311]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82) [?:1.8.0_311]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. JMeter .[jmx scripts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) are [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) files
2. `&#x0` is [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)
3. As per [Valid characters in XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML) article:

   > Note that the code point U+0000, assigned to the null control character, is the only character encoded in Unicode and ISO/IEC 10646 that is **always invalid** in any XML 1.0 and 1.1 document.

So the solution would be opening the .jmx script in a text/hex editor of your choice, look for all the occurrences of the null character and delete them.

There is a chance that the null character appeared because the .jmx script was saved using one [encoding](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding) and you're trying to open it in another encoding so you could try playing with the `file.encoding` system property by trying to pass various possible encodings via [-D command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) or putting them to [*system.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) but this chance is quite minimal.